Is there a rule involving or a name for rolls that will always be successful but high rolls will yield extra results?
To clarify, let us assume that Janet, player of a cleric Jainet, wants to know if Jainet knows about the god of the cult the group is dealing with. The DM knows that the god the cult worships is the mortal enemy of Jainet's god so it would be odd if Jainet did not know about it. So the DM says "Your character would know about them, but let's see how much they actually know." and has Janet roll religion. Janet gets a 4, they rolled a 2, and intelligence was not their strong suit. The DM says "Jainet knows that this god is chaotic evil and engages in human sacrifice but not much else."
Is there a term for such a roll where the player is guaranteed to get something but exceeding a certain threshold will yield better results? I am not looking for an answer from a particular edition as I am trying to find the term to refer to what I am saying as opposed to particular mechanics the term entails.

This case is probably made up, but I feel that most situations like you describe can be dealt with by telling what is obviously known (i.e. chaotic evil etc) and different knowledge roll(s), in this case probably religion, to check if the character knows lesser known facts (this deity declared puppies anathema).
This also allows different ways of knowing different things with different DC (religion, local knowledge, history, ...)

“Degrees of Success”
The 5e (2024) DMG calls this Degrees of Success:

Degrees of Success
A successful D20 Test can have degrees of success. For example, when characters participate in an archery contest, you might decide that the more an attack roll exceeds the target’s AC, the higher the character’s score. The archery target might have AC 11, but it has five concentric rings indicating degrees of success. So you could decide that an attack roll of 11 or 12 lands in the outermost ring, a 13 or 14 hits the next ring closer to the center, a 15 or 16 hits the third ring, a 17 or 18 hits the fourth, and a 19 or higher strikes the bull’s-eye.

This is a notable addition to the 2024 edition, as the 2014 DMG only featured sections for Success at a Cost (which is very similar) and Degrees of Failure.

Success at a Cost should be quite different than just degrees of success. I don't know how the DMG defines it but it should involve the character sacrificing something to fully succeed. They may block the blow but their shield is damaged in the process. Or irrevocably burn a precious memory to block a mental assault. Degrees of success don't have this element to them. At most the "cost" was same as what you get on failure. But a bit less. Instead of not knowing something, you'd know parts or instead of not doing damage, you do less damage.

Success at a cost is FATE, not DnD, although could be applied in a DnD context.

@Wyrmwood The section immediately preceding the one I quote from the D&D DMG has a big bold header that reads “Success at a Cost”.

@Wyrmwood it's hardly bound to one game. Apocalypse World games also do this with the roll 2d6 and a result in the 7-9 range will be a weak hit (comes with a cost although it might also be just partial success). Also have a look at Ironsworn for a beautiful PbtA reimagining with succeeding at a cost. It's a free RPG, after all, it deserves the attention.

The DMG 2024 says about "Success at a Cost":
"When a character fails a D20 Test by only 1 or 2, you can offer to let the character succeed at the cost of a complication or hindrance. Such complications can run along any of the following lines: - A character gets her sword past an enemy's defenses and turns a near miss into a hit, but she then drops the sword. - [...]"

I'm not sure this quite answers the question. The outcome of such a roll is a 'Degree of Success' but what type of roll is this? The DMG example refers to a roll with a DC, after all.
I would personally say that @Maiko Chikyu is asking for a name for the special case of tests with 'Degrees of Success' where the DC is zero/basic success is automatic.
